# Initialize the Attributes property of a WebControl object using collection initializer

Tags: c#, asp.net, initialization, collection-initializer

I want to initialize `WebControl` objects, inline, but for some fields this is a little bit tricky. For instance when I try to initialize the `Attributes` property of a [`TextBox`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/TextBox.cs,3b6d1ab0dca8c91a) object like this:

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
Panel panel = new Panel() { Controls = { new TextBox() { Attributes = { { "key", "value" } } } } };
```

I get the error:

> Cannot initialize type '[AttributeCollection](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/AttributeCollection.cs,c7c75273d5d13492)' with a collection
>   initializer because it does not implement
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Any idea how could inline initialization work in this case ?

Comment: Your question sounds similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668572/htmlgenericcontrol-attributes-in-object-initializer), and the accepted answer says that it's not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this but if you use C#6. This is called *index initialization* so try the following code but as I said this should works fine in Visual Studio 2015 and C#6:

```
Panel panel = new Panel
{
    Controls =
    {
        new TextBox
        {
            Attributes =
            {
                ["readonly"] = "true",
                ["value"] = "Hi"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The old collection initializers (*Prior to C#6*) only works with types that implement [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) and have an `Add` method. But now any type with an indexer will allow initialization via this syntax.